# Несколько Join таблицы саму на себя

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql

Существует 3 таблицы. Таблица product

```
 CREATE TABLE `product` (
 `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `model` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `quantity` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
 `date_available` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1990-09-02',
 `viewed` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
 `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
 KEY `date_modified` (`date_modified`),
 KEY `quantity_image` (`quantity`,`image`),
 KEY `model` (`model`),
 KEY `manufacturer_id` (`manufacturer_id`),
 KEY `price` (`price`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=125826 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Таблица attribute

```
CREATE TABLE `attribute` (
 `attribute_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `value` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`attribute_id`),
 KEY `attribute_id_name_value` (`attribute_id`,`name`,`value`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=657 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Таблица product_to_attribute

```
CREATE TABLE `product_attribute` (
 `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `attribute_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`attribute_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

В реальности имеем товары, которые содержать несколько атрибутов, 1 и больше.

Необходимо получать товары по заданным атрибутам. В качестве реализации использую вот такой запрос:

```
    SELECT p.model,
         p.product_id,
            
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_attribute AS pa1
    ON (p.product_id=pa1.product_id)
INNER JOIN product_attribute AS pa2
    ON (p.product_id=pa2.product_id)
INNER JOIN product_attribute AS pa3
    ON (p.product_id=pa3.product_id)
INNER JOIN product_attribute AS pa4
    ON (p.product_id=pa4.product_id)
INNER JOIN product_attribute AS pa5
    ON (p.product_id=pa5.product_id)
INNER JOIN product_attribute AS pa6
    ON (p.product_id=pa6.product_id)
INNER JOIN product_attribute AS pa7
    ON (p.product_id=pa7.product_id)
INNER JOIN product_attribute AS pa8
    ON (p.product_id=pa8.product_id)
WHERE p.quantity > 0
        AND pa1.attribute_id IN (12, 23)
        AND pa2.attribute_id IN (2, 37, 42, 54, 1)
        AND pa3.attribute_id IN (4, 38)
        AND pa4.attribute_id IN (535)
        AND pa5.attribute_id IN (7, 13)
        AND pa6.attribute_id IN (418, 368, 237)
        AND pa7.attribute_id IN (8, 14, 41)
        AND pa8.attribute_id IN (24, 22, 2) AND p2c.category_id IN (15, 5) AND p.manufacturer_id IN (197, 62, 4) AND p.price BETWEEN 32317 AND 1000000 GROUP BY p.model LIMIT 0,60
```

Если атрибутов до 5, то скорость выполнения приемлема, если 8 и больше, то скорость > 20 cек.

В качестве СУБД использую MySQL 5.7.31.

Записей в product > 150 000, attribute 600, product_to_attribute >  500 000 и база будет расти.

Не могли бы вы подсказать или натолкнуть как правильно оптимизировать скорость выполнения запросов?

Comment: можно пример данных (строк 10 хотя бы, желательно в формате INSERT'ов)? чтобы EXPLAIN на фидле хотя бы посмотреть... и `p2c.category_id IN (15, 5)` ни как не влияет на сложность запроса?

Comment: @para_bit Вам совершенно точно не нужно более одного join'а

Comment: Как первый шаг, можно заменить все джойны на `WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM prod_attr WHERE product_id=p.id AND attribute_id IN (12, 23))`. хотя, это почти то же самое)

Comment: @Fat-Zer добрый день, не совсем понимаю, что Insert-ы для каких именно таблиц нужны, если нужен какой-либо Explain, скажите, я покажу, p2c.category_id IN (15, 5) джойнить ещё одну таблицу, но суть именно в атрибутах.

Comment: @Ordman как тогда сделать без них?

Comment: @vp_arth да, думал в сторону подзапросов, смутило именно то, что практически одно и то же, но, наверно сейчас попробую, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT model, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(product_id) product_ids -- группировка только по model -
                                            -- обязательна агрегатная функция
FROM product
GROUP BY model
HAVING SUM(attribute_id IN (12, 23) AND category_id IN (15, 5))
   AND SUM(attribute_id IN (2, 37, 42, 54, 1))
-- ...  
   AND SUM(attribute_id IN (8, 14, 41))
   AND SUM(attribute_id IN (24, 22, 2))
   AND manufacturer_id IN (197, 62, 4) 
   AND p.price BETWEEN 32317 AND 1000000
ORDER BY ?????       -- LIMIT без сортировки - это лотерея
LIMIT 0,60
```

Если СУБД PostgreSQL - возможно, придётся добавить ко всем суммам `SUM(...) > 0`.

Comment: Модифицировал предложенный вами запрос, попробовал выполнить, но он не исполнился, я что то не так указал? (СУБД MySQL)

SELECT model, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(p.product_id) product_ids 
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_attribute
GROUP BY model
HAVING SUM(attribute_id IN (12, 23))
   AND SUM(attribute_id IN (2, 37, 42, 54, 1))
   AND SUM(attribute_id IN (8, 14, 41))
   AND SUM(attribute_id IN (24, 22, 2))
LIMIT 0,60

Comment: @para_bit Да делайте с ним что угодно - лишь бы результат был верным. Главное - показать принцип. *но он не исполнился* Не бывает. Или неверный результат (в чём неверен?), или сообщение об ошибке (какое?). *я что то не так указал?* Я откуда знаю... создайте online fiddle и покажите суть проблемы.

Comment: PHPMYADMIN запрос уходит на выполнение и ничего не возвращает, такое ощущение, что процесс виснет, я попробую сделать sql online fiddle

Comment: @para_bit Делайте на dbfiddle.uk - он поудобнее прочих.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=02cbf811b1921a65265458a4d5927082 добавил в фидл, но запрос возвращается пустой

Comment: @para_bit Фигню добавил нерабочую. Второй запрос заканчивается на `,`, а не на `;`. Если это поправить - выдаётся *Unknown column 'sp_auto_select' in 'field list'*. Размещай один запрос на блок, чтобы видеть сообщения об ошибках, или контролируй, что количество чеков равно количеству запросов. И не понимаю, зачем выгружать так дофига записей? десяток-другой вполне достаточно. И поля ненужные для смысла запроса - можно поскипать.

Comment: не могли бы вы ещё раз посмотреть https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=64cbefd164454e65ab990864e1b4de5a, первые два блока отрабатывают сделал минимум данных

Comment: @para_bit Ну если поправить косяки синтаксиса (имена, скобки, алиасы) и убрать дубли при конкатенации - то вполне себе работает... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=98a7ca75ee885fba2edc4425163410dc

Comment: я вам очень благодарен, потестирую на скорость и отпишу по итогам сюда, вам больше спасибо!

Comment: Добрый день, я провел тесты, результаты изложил в отдельном ответе, в этом же вопросе

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать поднять условия в join'ы:

```
 SELECT p.model,
         p.product_id
            
FROM oc_product p
JOIN oc_product_attribute a1 ON a1.product_id=p.product_id AND a1.attribute_id IN (5)
JOIN oc_product_attribute a2 ON a2.product_id=p.product_id AND a2.attribute_id IN (6)
JOIN oc_product_attribute a3 ON a3.product_id=p.product_id AND a3.attribute_id IN (7)
WHERE p.quantity > 0
```

Или перенести join'ы в подзапросы фильтра:

```
SELECT p.model,
         p.product_id
FROM oc_product p
WHERE p.quantity > 0
  AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM oc_product_attribute WHERE 
    product_id=p.product_id and attribute_id IN (5))
  AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM oc_product_attribute WHERE 
    product_id=p.product_id and attribute_id IN (6))
  AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM oc_product_attribute WHERE 
    product_id=p.product_id and attribute_id IN (7));
```

[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8b0217fa85a3ce54d291fb88dd378f0e)

Также я добавил в фиддл пару запросов, из которых можно понять, как работает решение от @Akina:

```
SELECT p.product_id, MIN(p.model) model, GROUP_CONCAT(attr.attribute_id)
FROM oc_product p 
INNER JOIN oc_product_attribute attr ON attr.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE p.quantity > 0
GROUP BY p.product_id 
HAVING SUM(attr.attribute_id IN (5)) > 0
  AND  SUM(attr.attribute_id IN (6)) > 0
  AND  SUM(attr.attribute_id IN (7)) > 0
```

Comment: и замена `JOIN`'ов на подзапросы, и перемещение условий в `ON` — бессмысленная затея... такие манипуляции почти никогда не влияют на план запроса, а следовательно не дают никакого заметного эффект на производительности...

Comment: Вообще, от базы зависит. Не у всех достаточно умные планировшики. Не все базы - postgres) Те же exists мне помогли в Firebird2.5 пару раз, без них памяти не хватало) Но в целом да, согласен.

Comment: Добрый день, я провел тесты, результаты изложил в отдельном ответе, в этом же вопросе

Answer (score 1):

По итогам получилось 3 вида запросов:

Запрос с множеством JOIN (1)

```
SELECT p.model, p.product_id
FROM oc_product p
LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c ON (p.product_id = p2c.product_id)
INNER JOIN oc_product_attribute as pa1 ON (p.product_id=pa1.product_id)
......
INNER JOIN oc_product_attribute as pa8 ON (p.product_id=pa8.product_id)
WHERE p.quantity > 0 AND 
pa1.attribute_id IN (10) 
.....
AND pa8.attribute_id IN (632,103) AND p2c.category_id IN (46, 81, 1)
AND p.manufacturer_id IN (4)
GROUP BY p.model, p.product_id
```

Запрос, который предложил @Akina (2)

```
SELECT model, product_id
FROM oc_product p 
INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c USING (product_id)
INNER JOIN oc_product_attribute pa USING (product_id)
   Where p.quantity > 0 AND p.manufacturer_id IN (4) AND p2c.category_id IN (1, 46, 81)
   GROUP BY model, product_id
HAVING SUM(pa.attribute_id IN (2, 33))
....
AND SUM(pa.attribute_id IN (632, 103))
```

И третий запрос от пользователя @vp_arth (3)

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE  p.model,
         p.product_id
FROM oc_product p
INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c USING (product_id)
INNER JOIN oc_product_attribute pa USING (product_id)
   Where p.quantity > 0 AND p.manufacturer_id IN (4) AND p2c.category_id IN (1, 46, 81)
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM oc_product_attribute WHERE 
    product_id=p.product_id and attribute_id IN (2, 33))
.....
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM oc_product_attribute WHERE 
    product_id=p.product_id and attribute_id IN (4, 38))
GROUP BY p.model,
         p.product_id
```

По итогам тестов пришел к следующим выводам:

1. При работе с количеством атрибутов от 1 до 7

- Запрос (1) 0.53 сек. - Время выполнения варьируется от от 0.1 до 0.5
  сек в зависимости от кол-ва типов атрибутов.
- Запрос (2) 0.9647 сек. Время выполнения практически одинаковое
- Запрос (3) 0.6429 сек - Время выполнения практически одинаковое

2. При работе с количеством атрибутов от 7 до 12

- Запрос (1) > 2 сек
- Запрос (2) 0.9815 сек - Практически не изменяется
- Запрос (3) 0.6729 сек - Время выполнения практически одинаковое

Но вопрос остается - неужели нет какого-то другого средства для оптимизации данного вида запроса?